# AngularJS: dynamically loaded component not showing

Tags: .net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, razorengine, dynamic-content

I have inherited a project which uses a mix of AngularJS and JQuery. I am currently having issues with a dynamically loaded `md-switch` directive not displaying when it is loaded dynamically. Please see the following:

In my view, I have

```
...
<md-switch class="md-primary md-switch-custom-margin" aria-label="Done Switch" ng-model="done"
          ng-change="markDone($event, @Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(!Model.Done))" />
...
```

On first page load, this control shows just fine. However on button click, I go retrieve a fresh partial view for the container that the `md-switch` lives in via ajax like so:

```
 $.ajax({
  url: "../../MyController/GetPartial",
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "html"
}).done(function (response) {
  $("#body-container").html(response);

  var angularScope = angular.element("div[ng-controller='MyAngularController'").scope();

  //have tried both of the following
  //angularScope.$apply();

})
```

When the partial view is loaded into the page, all of my `md-switch`s on the page are not visible although they do appear on the DOM and seem to be formatted just the same as before any action occurs.

After reviewing numerous posts, I'm still not sure what I'm missing here. All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution to my problem using `$compile` as follows in my jquery script:

the done callback of my ajax request:

```
       .done(function (response) {

          //have angular recompile it's dom directives such as md-switch
          angular.element(document.body).injector().invoke(function ($compile) {
            var container = $("#body-container");
            var scope = container.scope();
            container.html(response);
            $compile(container.contents())(scope);
          })
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

md-switch directive / component is not linked and not compiled, so angular dont recognize it

Comment: so you're saying there is no solution to this problem as things are currently structured ?

Comment: yes, you have to load the template and use compile service, i think something like this: https://gist.github.com/umidjons/1fb8ae674df4c71f85cf